# Check that property matches pattern

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, nant

Using NAnt, I'd like to check that my property matches the following pattern: `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`.

I have tried this so far:

```
    <condition property="check-my-prop">
      <matches pattern="[1-9a-zA-Z_]" string="${MyProp}"/>
    </condition>
    <fail message="my-prop must match pattern [1-9a-zA-Z_]"
          unless="check-my-prop" />
```

NAnt throws an error: `Invalid element <condition>. Unknown task or datatype.`

Code is adapted from Ant, not NAnt.

How can I achieve the same goal?

Comment: I think it happens because [there is no such a task](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.92/help/tasks/index.html) in NAnt. Perhaps, you'd need a [custom script](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.92/help/tasks/script.html).

Comment: You can explore [this](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.92/help/tasks/regex.html) too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <property name="CheckMyProp" value="" />
    <regex pattern="^(?'CheckMyProp'[1-9a-zA-Z_]+)$" input="${MyProp}" failonerror="false"/>    
    <if test="${string::get-length(CheckMyProp) == 0}">
      <fail>MyProp must match pattern [1-9a-zA-Z_]</fail>
    </if>
```